# Display extracted element via Jsoup to JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jsoup

I'm using JSoup to extract element in  tag. This is the result when I use .text() :

```
ACCOUNT
0000001
0000002
0000003

NAME
Customer1
Customer2
Customer3

BALANCE
100.00
200.00
550.00
```

I want to display it to the table that I've been created using JTable.I need someone to guide me to solve this problem with some examples code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class SimpleTable {
    public SimpleTable(){                                                                  
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        Object[][] tableInputs = {
        { 
            "Customer1","0000001", "100.00",
        },
        { 
            "Customer2", "0000002", "200.00"
        },
        { 
            "Customer3", "0000003", "550.00"
        }};
        String[] header = { "NAME", "ACCOUNT", "BALANCE" };
        JTable table = new JTable(tableInputs, header);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 100));
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        f.add(scrollPane);
        f.setTitle("Simple Table");
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleTable b = new SimpleTable();
    }
}
```

Comment: what if the size of extracted element is not fix? Because we don't know the size of table (row and column), the size depend on the table in the web page that user want. it could be 3x4 or 4x4, we don't know, so how to make the code dynamic?